# Complain on moderator Paul White's violating privacy and suffocating speech

Tags: support, moderation

I am complaining https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/paul-white-9.

As Paul White ordered us not to continue some discussion earlier, I stopped. But some user started doxing my other accounts, and Paul White facilitated doxing. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53552840#53552840

> You can also use SEDE of course

This moderator also ignores my flags that requested removing the doxing comments.
If SE sites allow users to protect their accounts on other sites and some users do so, it means that the users don't want their other accounts to be doxed. That should be respected, even when the SE policies and features are  incoherent and when you can dox me from technical perspective. I have been victims of doxing in  meta sites and chatroom several times. 
This moderator continues to provide ways for doxing in his reply here. He continues to show no  respect for privacy and   ethics.

Since the moderator let the doxing going, and moreover, some users brought up again the  previous discussion that insulted me, and the moderator also let it going, I had to fight. [A user named Tom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/147768/tom-v-try-topanswers-xyz), whose avatar shows he has been  fighting for Monica, complained  "not again". I found that to be hypocrite. I wrote in https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53554350#53554350, which Paul White has moved to trash, that they have been pushing  the fight between the powerful people in the community again and again  everywhere everyday. Then  "Tom"   insulted me:

> you are just boring us to death with incoherent babbling

Paul White acted biased again, by putting me on suspension in the chatroom.

Moderator should live up to a high standard. It is unacceptable to protect acquaintances and persecute complainers. Paul White is an unethical  and unjust   moderator. I recommend Paul White to resign.

---

All the descriptions above are sufficient for the complaints on the misconducts of the moderator,  without going into the  discussions that happened earlier.

The moderator doesn't seem to be able to defend himself. He started to divert attention away from the complaints on him.

- My cross site reputations have nothing to do with my complaints on the moderator.  If you moderator want to talk about them here, I do not belong to the same community and social classes as you and your elite acquaintances. I do not use my reputations and powers to humiliate other users and suppress posting of other users. On the contrary, my posting has  been suppressed by  you and your "elite" friends.  My reputations on dba are quite low and make me  more vulnerable to the subjective downvotes and close votes.  We also belong to completely different social classes. Your classes are ruling others, and your culture glorifies power and fortune (even by invasion and slavery). You are privileged and everything comes so much easier because of your race, language, class and culture.
- My posts on the mainsite have nothing to do with my complaints on the moderator here. If you moderator want to talk about them here, my posts can't be changed. Any change will change what I meant. Everything can be written in a book, and everything can be summarized in a few sentences when knowing the idea. When you don't feel comfortable about a question, it means that it is not at your comfort level, and not that you and your elite acquaintances should suffocate my post.
- The ban on my account on the main site has nothing to do with my complaints on the moderator here.   It is systematic discrimination from  the site policy and  the attacking users. If you moderator really care about it, you can try to do something with them. But you don't.
- My  asking   questions earlier in the chatroom was irrelevant to my complaint on the moderator too, and the moderator was not even involved in the communication. If you moderator want to talk about it,  they asked if I was a child, and if I was Evan. They dismissed my questions by that answering my question would take writing a book, cooking rice and chicken. I played nice   and tried to invoke the same from them, and dragged the conversation back to the questions over and over again. The communication was very difficult, painful, humiliating, condescending and futile.

This site just like many other SE sites is for the privileged heartless and their sycophants, not for ordinary users.  Changes are never made from top down. Spending time to convince themselves they are wrong is destined to fail.  Completely not worth it. Majority of the victim users are silenced or don't waste time to voice. That is exactly what the ruling "elite" class of this community wants. Purely evil.

Answer (score 17):

#### Network reputation

You mentioned many times in chat being "at the bottom of the community". Understandably, this provoked questions from other people since your [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/4432/tim) shows 183k network rep earned since 2011, despite your home site being The Great Outdoors, where you have only 101 rep:

[image: chat profile]

You further drew attention to this when [you said](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53551505#53551505):

> I have been bullied on StackOverflow and several sites. Otherwise, that is not my current reputations

#### Hidden communities

The [*Hide Communities* page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/current) says:

[image]

Your network activity is **not private**, and there are several well-known ways for ordinary users (and even people not logged in to any site) to find your other communities using only public information and [site links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292506), or [the mobile apps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327277/hidden-communities-not-working-in-mobile).

- [Accounts (on the activity tab) links to network profile even if the community is hidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292506)

This has been discussed many times on main meta e.g. in [Fix the misleading description of the “Hide Communities” feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274351) where Jon Ericson  (then a Community Manager) says:

> The only real way to maintain separation in your activity on the network is the old-fashioned way: **maintain separate accounts using separate credentials**.

As noted in chat, account and site profile information is also available on the public Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE). A popular example query can be found [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/678540/list-of-communities-of-an-user-included-the-hidden-ones).

Since the information is **public** (not private or PII), the question of "doxing" does not arise for me. As an aside, if you were truly concerned with privacy, I would expect you to contact the company in private rather than drawing yet more attention to your account via this meta question.

#### Chat

I did not see any chat flags, and so did not handle them. As far as I can tell from the logs, your flags were declined by a different chat moderator somewhere else on the network.

Your 24 hour chat suspension is for continuing to disrupt The Heap chat room after being told to stop. You could use this time to improve the [poorly-received question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/259700/how-are-migrations-done) that led to your system-imposed [question ban](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) on the main site. Our chat regulars were polite and helpful, answering your too-broad question in chat, until you [started to rant](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53545962#53545962) about the question ban. Chat users must take responsibility for their own actions. If you see something unacceptable posted by someone else, [disengage and flag if appropriate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271268).

Local moderators can't be around 24 hours a day to baby sit chat. When I logged on this morning I saw a heap of messages ranting about your question ban again. In my judgement, you were the root cause of the disruption, so a short chat ban was issued. The offending messages (not just yours) were moved to a trash room.

You may wish to take your complaints up with SO Inc. To do that, send a message via the ["Contact" link](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) at the bottom of every page.

Answer (score 11):

I am just going to analyse your question as the sentences flow across the screen.

> QUESTION: I am complaining https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/paul-white-9.

That is rather strange as Paul is one of the few I would call the central foundation of our community. Paul is never really biased and will allow communication in The Heap™ to flow rather than to disrupt it, unless it becomes too volatile.

> QUESTION: As Paul White ordered us not to continue some discussion earlier, I stopped.

**So based on the actions of yourself and/or some other user**, you were told by a moderator that it might be beneficial for the community, that this discussion be not continued? But if I read the chat correctly you continued.

> QUESTION: ... But **some user started doxing my other accounts**, and Paul White facilitated doxing. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53552840#53552840
>
> > You can also use SEDE of course

So **some user** started doxing you? I guess this means that the actual complaint should be made towards **that user** and not towards the moderator? Paul's message pointing out that SEDE can be used to search the StackExchange database is very marginally *facilitating*. I would even go so far as to state **StackExchanage** is the actual facilitator in this case, as they provide the ways and means to *facilitate* doxing.

**By the way** what is your private information doing on the internet? If you don't want private information on the internet to be doxed, then please don't store it there, where it can be accessed by millions of internet users.

And do you really fully understand the meaning of **doxing**?

> ...search for and publish private or identifying information about (a particular individual) on the Internet, typically with malicious intent.

Where is the malicious intent? I couldn't find any malicious intent.

> QUESTION:  This moderator also ignores my flags that requested removing the doxing comments.

As has been previously pointed out: There is no **the moderator**. Paul is not available 24 hours a day for moderation tasks. He lives a life like most of the people on this site and tends for his income, family and friends. Not always on this site.

> QUESTION:  ...If SE sites allow users to protect their accounts on other sites and some users do so, it means that the users don't want their other accounts to be doxed. That should be respected, even when the SE policies and features are incoherent and when you can dox me from technical perspective.

This something you would have to discuss with StackExchange and you might have to look at the privacy policy again where there is written:

<sub>(**emphasis** mine)</sub>

> Stack Exchange Inc. is the controller responsible for your personal data.
>   ...
>   You may choose to provide certain "special category" data about you (such as data about your race or ethnicity, religious or philosophical beliefs, sex life, sexual orientation, political opinions) in connection with your use of our Public Network. If you do, we will hold and process this data in accordance with our privacy policy.
>   ...
>   We may collect, use, store and transfer different kinds of personal data about you which we have grouped together as follows:
>   ...
>   Profile Data: including your username and password, your interests, preferences, feedback and survey responses.
>   ...
>   Direct interactions: **you may give us personal information** by filling in forms or by corresponding with us by mail, phone, email, in person at events, as part of our contractual arrangement with you, **by inputting that data into one of our customer facing platforms, or otherwise.** This includes **personal data you provide** when you order or express an interest in our products or services; **subscribe to our services or publications**; request marketing to be sent to you; enter a competition, promotion or survey; or give us some feedback.
>   ...

<sup>***Reference:*** [Privacy Notice for the Public Network](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy/public-network) (stackoverflow)</sup>

I hope you understand the general direction I am going? If you have personal information you don't want discovered, then you might want to consider not putting it here on Stackexchange/stackoverflow.

> QUESTION: I have been victims of doxing in meta sites and chatroom several times. This moderator continues to provide ways for doxing in his reply here. He continues to show no respect for privacy and ethics.

Again. Wrong. The network provides ways for doxing. The moderator just responded to sentence in chat:

> that doesn't answer how you got 183k
>   @EvanCarroll You can find network accounts from dba.stackexchange.com/users/… if you know where to click.
>   You can also use SEDE of course

No facilitating in my opinion. You still require knowledge what to use in SEDE to find related accounts and/or information.

> QUESTION: Since the moderator let the doxing going, and moreover, some users brought up again the previous discussion that insulted me, and the moderator also let it going, I had to fight. A user named Tom, whose avatar shows he has been fighting for Monica, complained "not again". I found that to be hypocrite.

I can't find anything in that statement that would make Tom a hypocrite:

> Definition of hypocriate: someone who says they have particular moral beliefs but behaves in way that shows these are not sincere

Nope, the definition does not seem to match the statement you made.

> QUESTION: I wrote in https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53554350#53554350, which Paul White has moved to trash, that they have been pushing the fight between the powerful people in the community again and again everywhere everyday. Then "Tom" insulted me:
>
> > you are just boring us to death with incoherent babbling

Tom was just stating a fact there. The whole discussion that erupted after your migration question, which if I recall correctly I answered as best as possible, was just way too broad.

> YOU: Paul White acted biased again, by putting me on suspension in the chatroom.

I would object. Your whole attitude went from piling up question after question on a theoretical subject, to being slightly aggressive:

> Thanks for all the help. Sorry for any discomfort and entertainment
>   I hope that I have made your boring Friday afternoon pass a little quicker
>   ...
>   This is not right.
>   unjust.
>   unfair
>   elitism
>   oligarchy
>   authoritarian
>   I can't think of a proper word to describe this horrible thing
>   One undervalued post, dubious downvotes and close votes, nightmare
>   ...
>   I am not here to educate you why I can't see them

After which there was a response from Paul:

> Lose the attitude buddy

With which you responded:

> this site doesn't try to build a friendly constructive atmosphere.

I find that disturbing, as we are one of the friendliest, welcoming communities on SE in my opinion. Your questions were answered in a friendly manner, as far a that can go in a chat community, where there is no obligation to do so. But as your attitude changed, you were reminded that you should possibly rethink. Which you decided not to.

> QUESTION: Moderator should live up to a high standard. It is unacceptable to protect acquaintances and persecute complainers. Paul White is an unethical and unjust moderator. I recommend Paul White to resign.

Paul lives up to a very high standard. From what I read Paul did not protect any acquaintances and he did not persecute a complainer. However, a moderator did put a temporary ban on a person that was becoming slightly aggressive and which was not living up to the friendly welcoming atmosphere we have a DBA.SE.

I'm sorry if you feel otherwise.

Answer (score -11):

After thorough reflection and examination, I agree Tim. It's time we unite.

If you will accept my apology, I'll run in the next moderator election. If I can count on your vote I'll make one of the first 10 things I do a two-week suspension for the **entire** mod team here for their past infractions.

This nonsense has gone on too long. It's not quite Hitler, but certainly it would bring a tear to Mousilini to see all his wishes and aspirations at play here.

I take it all back. You are no longer `Tim [from StackOverfl*w]`. Henceforth you'll just be `Tim`. Let's never speak of this again.